# On usages like "I saw the thief escape on a boat"

Tags: word-usage

In the sentence, "I saw a thief escape on a boat.", what part of speech is "escape"? Is it used as a verb or a noun? Please elaborate on usages like these.

Comment: It would be a noun in something like *I saw a fire escape on the side of the building,* but in your example it's unquestionably a ***verb***. An "unmarked infinitive" (without ***to***), I guess, since it wouldn't change form if we switched the singular "subject" from ***a thief*** to plural ***several thieves***.

Comment: Could you explain what "an unmarked infinitive" is, so that I can better understand usages like these?

Comment: An example of an unmarked infinitive would be *You should **study** my comment more carefully*. The highlighted word is definitely a verb, but one way to tell it's an infinitive is that it's still the same form regardless of whether I change ***you*** to ***she*** or ***they***. Whereas it's *not* an infinitive in, say, ***She studies** carefully* or ***They study** carefully*, where the verb form changes according to whether the subject is singular or plural. And it's "unmarked" because it doesn't have the "infinitive marker" ***to*** that occurs in, say, *He intends **to study** carefully*.

Comment: It's a verb, an infinitival form to be precise. This is called a complex catenative construction, where "saw" is a catenative verb and the infinitival clause "escape on a boat" is its catenative complement. The intervening noun phrase "the thief" is the syntactic object of "saw", and the _understood_ subject of "escape". It's called a raised object.

Comment: @BillJ That comment would make a great answer!

Comment: @Tashus Good point - done!

Answer (score 1):

> *I saw a thief [escape on a boat]*.

"Escape" is a verb -- an infinitival form to be precise. This is called a complex catenative construction, where "saw" is a catenative verb and the infinitival clause "escape on a boat" is its catenative complement.

The intervening noun phrase "a thief" is the syntactic object of "saw", and the understood (semantic) subject of "escape". It's called a raised object because the verb it relates to syntactically is higher in the constituent structure than the verb it relates to semantically.

The word 'catenative' comes from the Latin word for "chain", which is appropriate here since "saw" and "escape" form a chain of verbs separated only by the NP "a thief".

Comment: Sorry if I am being too naïve, but, if "escape" is a verb, shouldn't it agree with its singular subject "a thief"? I know it doesn't sound right but what would be the grammatical explanation for it?

Comment: @Max_P No, because "escape" is an infinitival verb (the base form), so it has no number agreement (or tense). "Saw" is the main verb in the sentence.